# Save Changed Text Of a TextView

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an Button in my first activity which changes it background onclick and save with SharedPreferences , but I want to set one more code that when I check the button it set the text of a TextView in my second activity to "Button-Checked" and when I uncheck it set the text of the TextView to "Button-Unchecked" and then SAVE the text (with SharedPreferences or anything else).
In my first activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private boolean likechek;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button like = (Button) findViewById(R.id.like);
    like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Dog.this);
            sp.edit().putBoolean("like_", !likechek).commit();
            LikeAnalayzer();
        }
    });

}

    private void LikeAnalayzer() {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    likechek = sp.getBoolean("like_", false);
    UpdateLikeButton();
}

    private void UpdateLikeButton() {
    Button like = (Button) findViewById(R.id.like);

    if(likechek){
        like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starf);
    }else{
        like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);

    }

}           
}
```

and Second (its empty):

```
public class Fav extends Activity {
TextView tv ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fav);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answer , I really need it.

Comment: Where u are starting Second Activity?

Comment: In a navigationdrawer , it is the code:case 0 :
                  new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fav.class);
                  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this , Fav.class));
                  break;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to set the text to the textView if the button is checked, so you could do it like the change of the background like this for example:

```
private void UpdateLikeButton() {
    Button like = (Button) findViewById(R.id.like);
    TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if(likechek){
        like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starf);
        myTextView.setText("Button-Checked");
        //and save in the shared preferences the state:
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Dog.this);
        sp.edit().putString("button_state", "Button-Checked").commit();
    }else{
        like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);
        myTextView.setText("Button-Unchecked");
        //and save in the shared preferences the state:
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Dog.this);
        sp.edit().putString("button_state", "Button-Unchecked").commit();
    }

}
```

and if you want to set the text of the textView in the second activity just skip the part in the first one that is `myTextView.setText("Button-Checked");` like this:

```
private void UpdateLikeButton() {
    Button like = (Button) findViewById(R.id.like);

    if(likechek){
        like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starf);
        //and save in the shared preferences the state:
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Dog.this);
        sp.edit().putString("button_state", "Button-Checked").commit();
    }else{
        like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);
        //and save in the shared preferences the state:
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Dog.this);
        sp.edit().putString("button_state", "Button-Unchecked").commit();
    }

}
```

and do it in the second one like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fav);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String buttonState = sp.getString("button_state", "");
    tv.setText(buttonState);
}
```

Hopefully this helps you :)